# Customizing the splash screen of an Android app developed using PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova

I've got PhoneGap's example HelloWorld application running and currently when the app loads there is a splash screen that loads up that has their little robot and a grayscale gradient. I discovered that they appear to be inside the /www/res/screen/android directory andI tried to replace the files with my own but when I built the project they got overwritten by the grayscale + robot images. I looked at config.xml and it seems to just refer to the images I tried to replace before rather than being what defines the rules for generating the image. Where should I be looking for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was that I was editing the splash screen images in the platform-specific directories rather than the main project directory. As a result, the build process was overwriting the images.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start looking for it is the [documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_splashscreen_splashscreen.md.html). Before loading your first url you can set the splashscreen:

```
super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 10000);
```